# USB Drive Writing speed is so slow

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, speed, format

I have a 32gb sandisk usb drive. Today when i tried to copy some of the movies to my USB, it was so slow. I mean always the speed goes below 500kb. I used the drive even yesterday. I have faced no issues. It showed minimum speed of atleast 10 MB or something. I tried formatting many times and also in NTFS, fat32 etc.. Also when i tried ejecting the drive it takes more time. As i said i haven't faced any such issues before.

Comment: Try the drive on another computer, to see if it's a problem with it or with the computer.

Comment: @harrymc when i tried different usb on my pc no issues are there.

Comment: Try this USB on another device.

Comment: @harrymc I tried this on my windows tablet. Its the same. speed under 500kb/s.

Comment: @harrymc What do i do now?

Comment: USB sticks do not last forever and cannot be fixed. You need to get a new one.